# Outputting to a file from multiple functions

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm using

```
std::ofstream cout(output_path);
```

to output text to a file. If I try to use this call in both my main function and a separate function, the previous text data is erased from the file with each call. Is there a way to ensure that changes I make to the text file between calls are kept?

Comment: Don't keep opening the file, pass a reference to the opened file from main() to your function.

Comment: Create exactly one `ofstream` object and pass it (by reference) between functions, or make it global.

Comment: ^ Or that. Opening and closing file handle repeatedly is an expensive operation